# Animating CSS button with hot key

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the below code to animate a button press when the user clicks on it. It works fine, but I realized when I press the button with a hot key, I don't get the same effect. Is this because of the active::hover CSS attribute? If so what do I need to add or change to get the same effect when using the keyboard? I created this snippet to show what I mean.

And here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/SquanchyHappy/pen/bGWRBWN

```
<button id="button_test", class="button">Test</button>
```

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #311049; /*Button Color*/
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: hack;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: min(6vw, clamp(1rem, 4.5vh, 4rem));
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.2em black;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.button:hover:active {
    transition: 0.1s;
    box-shadow: 0.01em 0.02em black;
    transform: translate(0.05em, 0.1em);
}
.button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0.06em 0.12em black;
    transform: translate(-0.01em, -0.02em);
}
```

```
const button = document.getElementById("button_test");
document.addEventListener("keyup", pressButton);

button.onclick = changeText;

function pressButton(keypress) {
  button.click();
}

function changeText() {
  if (button.innerText === "Words") {
    button.innerText = "Test";
  } else {
    button.innerText = "Words";
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have an active class that contains the button active state styles and when key down add this class to your button class list and when key up remove that class. i hope this works for you:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button_test");
document.addEventListener("keydown", pressButton);
document.addEventListener("keyup", releaseButton);

function pressButton() {
   button.classList.add("active");
}

function releaseButton(){
  button.classList.remove("active");
  button.click();
}
```

```css
.active {
  transition: 0.1s;
    box-shadow: 0.01em 0.02em black;
    transform: translate(0.05em, 0.1em);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a button with the keyboard enables the elements `:focus` state and not the `:hover` state. For your example, just modify your hover style rule like this:

```css
.button:hover,
.button:focus { /* <- add this :focus pseudo selector */
    box-shadow: 0.06em 0.12em black;
    transform: translate(-0.01em, -0.02em);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that change didn't work for me. As another person pointed out, it's because I have a keyup event I'm using, so adding a keydown event first is what I was missing.